# wpf keyDown in while loop

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown, onkeydown

I am working on project called IAT. In two words, there are 2 categories in top corners (left, right), and a list of words, connected with these categories, randomly showed in the center of screen (1 word matches only one category).
After word is showed in the middle, program should "stop" and wait until user press key to sort word (left arrow for left category and right for the right). After user gave answer, program counts time wasted on answers. Then, the other word is showed and this process continues for several iterations.
To sum up, I want to make equivalent of RedKey(). While Debugging I realized that program doesn't react to pressed keys in while (true/stopwatch.IsRunning()/etc) loops. What should I do to make programm wait for user answer and react to it.

Comment: You have to show problematic code. Are you running loops in UI thread? To organize timeout while waiting for user action you can use a simple `Timer`. To measure the time - `Stopwatch` or `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When program is showing a word, you should start timer (***using System.Timers.Timer***), handle its Ellapsed event, inside handler you have to increment variable which will be your counter (how long user answers question)
Then in MainWindow's KeyDown event you can check if pressed key is left or right arrow, then if timer is enabled, if so, you know that question is ready to be answered, now just stop the timer, your counter variable will show amount of seconds in which user pressed arrow (of course you have to adjust Timer's interval).

Here you have full code (without just questions logic of course)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Timer answerTimeTimer; // it's for counting time of answer
    Timer questionTimer; // this is used for generating questions
    int timeOfAnswer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        questionTimer = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = 2500
        };


        answerTimeTimer = new Timer()
        {
            Interval = 1000 
        };

        answerTimeTimer.Elapsed += AnswerTimeTimer_Elapsed;
        questionTimer.Elapsed += QuestionTimer_Elapsed;

        questionTimer.Start();
    }

    private void QuestionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        AskQuestion();
    }

    private void AskQuestion()
    {
        //Your questions logic
        Console.WriteLine("Question asked");
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => label.Content = "Question asked")); // This line is just to update the label's text (it's strange because you need to update it from suitable thread)
        answerTimeTimer.Start();
        questionTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void AnswerTimeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timeOfAnswer++;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => label.Content = timeOfAnswer));
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            if (answerTimeTimer.Enabled)
            {
                answerTimeTimer.Stop();
                //Here you can save the time from timeOfAnswer
                Console.WriteLine("Question answered in " + timeOfAnswer);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => label.Content = "Question answered in " + timeOfAnswer));
                timeOfAnswer = 0; // Reset time for the next question
                questionTimer.Start();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

And just one label in XAML to show that everything works

```
<Label x:Name="label" Content="Right or left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

If you have any questions just ask :)